# OSX apache server cannot been open in chrome and firefox but can been open in safari

Tags: macos, apache, google-chrome

Tonight , I found my apache server cannot been open in chrome.
when I enter "localhost",It returns "No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".
But when I enter "localhost" in safari , It works.
So I don't know how to fix it,I can ping it In terminal,and I try to restart apache and my mac.but it doesn't work.

Comment: An empty response is different from a failing connection. I suggest you start taking a look into your http servers error log file where you can read what the issue is. Safari probably only delivers a cached version of the page you request...

Comment: It was not a cache version of the page.I can also open another new page from It.

Comment: Then maybe one group of browsers uses a proxy and the other does not. Whatever, doesn't change a thing. What do your error and access log files say?